# php+ajax+javascript: encodeURIComponent cuts my text when sending to the server

Tags: ajax, string, encodeuricomponent

This is my first question... I hope my problem doesn't look stupid...

html  (any symbols are allowed)  ---> javascript event ---> javascript function sends text to .php file using ajax method.
Here is a problem:

when I use
**xmlhttp.open("GET","proceed.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(str),false);**
it works great for small texts (less than 1500 symbols)....

If I use 
**xmlhttp.open("GET","proceed.php?q="+str,false);**
then it works for any length, but I have to be careful with special characters.

Why doesn't encodeURIComponent work for a bigger amount of text (over ~1500 even just simple alphanumeric symbols)?
Any ideas?

So, the problem is in this string (I've tested all the rest).

BTW, it was tested on bulgarian cyrillic letters...

With a text over 1500 symbols there is no action at all (no viewable mistake, no nothing, just nothing happens).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of limits which you can hit with the length of a URL. In IE, the total length of the URL, including a GET query string, [must not exceed 2,083 characters](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427). The server might [impose a limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Compatibility_issues), too.

So apparently it's not encodeURIComponent itself which has a problem with long strings. Rather, the encoded result is longer than the unencoded string, and that seems to be enough to make you hit one of the limits I mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I need. Switched from GET to POST method.