# Passing large encoded text from javascript (ajax) to a php file

Tags: javascript, encodeuricomponent

I have a JavaScript variable which contains a large text string - containing latex + HTML code. I want to encode this and pass it to a PHP page, where it can be decoded and acted upon by the PHP script. If i use encodeURIComponent(), there's a character limit involved. Please suggest any other way to encode and send this.

Comment: How are you going to pass the variable to php: AJAX, GET or some other way?

Comment: xmlhttp.open("GET","insert_question.php?     send_string="+send_string,true);
xmlhttp.send();
and size of send_string is much greater than 2000

Comment: You have to send data using POST method, not GET. There is a data lenght limit using GET method.

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7004593/phpajaxjavascript-encodeuricomponent-cuts-my-text-when-sending-to-the-server

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ajax, try posting the data.  The encoding is automatic and there is no size limit.  Are you using jQuery?  That would simplify matters.

Comment: I tried posting the data but nothing happens in that case. No entry into the SQL table is made in insert_question.php